# Java: Find out difference of a ByteBuffer created via channel.map and allocateDirect

Tags: java, nio

Is there a programmatical way to implement the method "isFileMapped" which satisfy the following:

```
 ByteBuffer aa = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(12);
 assertFalse(isFileMapped(aa));
 FileChannel fc = new RandomAccessFile(File.createTempFile("mmap", "test"), "rw").getChannel();
 ByteBuffer bb = fc.map(FileChannel.MapMode.READ_WRITE, 0, 10);
 assertTrue(isFileMapped(bb));
 fc.close();
 // and of course:
 assertFalse(isFileMapped(ByteBuffer.allocate(12)));
```

Both instances are of type MappedByteBuffer and are direct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `MappedByteBuffer.isLoaded()`. For really mapped buffers it returns true or false, for those returned by `ByteBuffer.allocateDirect()`, it throws UnsupportedOperationException.

But I am not sure if it would still throw UnsupportedOperationException after participating in an I/O operation.

Comment: Thanks this seems to do the trick. What do you mean with the last sentence? Do you mean when I e.g. copy my ByteBuffer into a file it could be that the allocateDirect Buffer does no longer throws an exception?

Comment: Yes, this is a trick, as it is not documented. I meant exactly what you say.

Comment: ok, thanks! That is too tricky ... I'll subclass and use a boolean or something.